# get complete list of categories with IDs from YQL

Tags: yql

I am using YQL to query Local.Search.. where are categories with IDs, I would like to get the whole list of these categories with their IDs, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo does not publish the list of categories with their corresponding ID numbers, so this list is not available anywhere (outside the company at least).